# accepts_nested_attributes_for keeps form fields from showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested

When I use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` the corresponding fields no longer show in my view.

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions   
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
end
```

Then in my view:

```
<%= form_for @survey do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :questions do |question_fields| %>
    <%= question_fields.text_area :text %> 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If I remove `accepts_nested_attributes_for` then the `text_area` shows, but if I keep it...nothing gets renders.

I'm running Rails 3.0.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you build the questions , in the controller ?

Something like

`@survey.questions.build`

This builds one related question, so only one text area will show up. run it in a loop like

`2.times { @survey.questions.build }`

It will appear 2 times.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to create new questions or are you editing them?  You might want to try something like this if you are creating a new question for this survey:

```
<= f.fields_for @survey.questions.build do |question_fields| %>
```